# How to lag a specific column of a data frame in R

Tags: r

Input 
(Say d is the data frame below.)

```
a  b  c
1  5  7
2  6  8
3  7  9
```

I want to shift the contents of column b one position down and put an arbitrary number in the first position in b. How do I do this? I would appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you.

I tried c(6,tail(d["b"],-1)) but it does not produce (6,5,6).

Output

```
a  b  c
1  6  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `head` instead

```
df$b <- c(6, head(df$b, -1))
#  a b c
#1 1 6 7
#2 2 5 8
#3 3 6 9
```

You could also use `lag` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(b = lag(b, default = 6))
```

Or `shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, b:= shift(b, fill = 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution uses `lag` with an explicit `default` argument, if you prefer:

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = 5:7, c = 7:9)

d %>% mutate(b = lag(b, default = 6))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <int> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     6     7
#> 2     2     5     8
#> 3     3     6     9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution similar to the `head` approach by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191834/12158757)

```
df <- within(df,b <- c(runif(1),b[-1]))
```

where a uniformly random variable is added to the first place of `b` column:

```
> df
  a         b c
1 1 0.6644704 7
2 2 6.0000000 8
3 3 7.0000000 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution below will help in any lag or lead position

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(5,6,7),c=c(7,8,9))

d1 <- d %>% arrange(b) %>% group_by(b) %>% 
mutate(b1= dplyr::lag(b, n = 1, default = NA))
```

Comment: This just creates a new `b1` column with all `NA`s?

Comment: No , it will create one lag of b column and default first value NA.