# How to lag multiple specific columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lag

I would like to lag multiple specific columns of a data frame in R.

Let's take this generic example. Let's assume I have defined which columns of my dataframe I need to lag:

```
Lag <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)
Lag.Index <- is.element(Lag, 1)
df <- data.frame(x1 = 1:8, x2 = 1:8, x3 = 1:8, x4 = 1:8)
```

My initial dataframe:

```
        x1  x2  x3  x4   
    1   1   1   1   1
    2   2   2   2   2
    3   3   3   3   3
    4   4   4   4   4 
    5   5   5   5   5
    6   6   6   6   6
    7   7   7   7   7
    8   8   8   8   8
```

I would like to compute the following dataframe:

```
        x1  x2  x3  x4   
    1   1   NA  1   NA
    2   2   2   2   2
    3   3   3   3   3
    4   4   4   4   4 
    5   5   5   5   5
    6   6   6   6   6
    7   7   7   7   7
    8   8   8   8   8
```

I would know how to do it for only one lagged column as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191834/7583734), but not able to find a way to do it for multiple lagged columns in an elegant way. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `purrr`'s `map2_dfc` to lag different values by column.

```
purrr::map2_dfc(df, Lag, dplyr::lag)

#     x1    x2    x3    x4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1    NA     1    NA
#2     2     1     2     1
#3     3     2     3     2
#4     4     3     4     3
#5     5     4     5     4
#6     6     5     6     5
#7     7     6     7     6
#8     8     7     8     7
```

Or with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, names(df) := Map(shift, .SD, Lag)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The two solutions are bright, and fit perfectly to my needs. I am not an expert in R, could you elaborate on what `.SD` do here please?

Comment: `.SD` is specific to data.table here it refers to all the columns in `df`. We can specify `SDcols` as `.SDcols  = 1:3` in which case `.SD` will refer to column 1 to 3 only.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option using `shift` along with `Vectorize`

```
> setDT(df)[, Vectorize(shift)(.SD, Lag)]
     x1 x2 x3 x4
[1,]  1 NA  1 NA
[2,]  2  1  2  1
[3,]  3  2  3  2
[4,]  4  3  4  3
[5,]  5  4  5  4
[6,]  6  5  6  5
[7,]  7  6  7  6
[8,]  8  7  8  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is elegant enough, but I would use `dplyr`'s mutate_at function to tweak columns

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate_at(.vars = vars(x2,x4),.funs = ~lag(., default = NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

We convert the `lag` to `logical` class, get the corresponding `names` and use `across` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
      mutate(across(names(.)[as.logical(Lag)], lag))
#  x1 x2 x3 x4
#1  1 NA  1 NA
#2  2  1  2  1
#3  3  2  3  2
#4  4  3  4  3
#5  5  4  5  4
#6  6  5  6  5
#7  7  6  7  6
#8  8  7  8  7
```

---

Or we can do this in `base R`

```
df[as.logical(Lag)] <- rbind(NA, df[-nrow(df), as.logical(Lag)])
```